# ¿Es conveniente indexar una columna de tipo char o varchar?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Mi duda surge ya que el numero de teléfono lo estoy guardando en un campo de tipo VARCHAR y pensaba usar este campo para buscar el id de cierto de registro y guardarla como FK, pero me preguntaba sí ¿es conveniente indexar este campo para hacer búsquedas?, o ¿Cómo me recomendarían guardar este dato y hacer búsquedas con ese campo?, de igual manera ¿creen que lo que estoy tratando de hacer sea correcto?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cuantas busquedas realmente vas a hacer por ese campo?  ese es uno de los datos que no suele indexarse...

Comment: Igual esta pregunta asi esta basada en opiniones... atras mio viene otra persona, te dice que si, y ya no hay respuesta....

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por la observación, la verdad es que si pienso hacer búsquedas continuamente sobre ese campo, creo que si falto algo de contexto en la pregunta igual para que me digan si lo que haré es correcto, la editaré.

Comment: Depende, si tenés un sistema en dónde el teléfono es un dato central, por ejemplo un sistema de delivery, es probable que convenga indexarlo, ahora en sistemas administrativos contables más tradicionales nunca vi una columna como telefono que formara parte de un índice.

Comment: A menos que se trate de un distribuidor de telefonía celular -por ejemplo- donde puedas estandarizar el número digamos a 10 dígitos, incluso podrías almacenarlo como número. Pero si tienes que almacenar códigos internacionales o números de extensión el caso es distinto.